# print row from csv file if a condition is met

Tags: csv

How can I print a row from csv file only if a condition is met in the following code ?

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',' )
for row in spamreader:
    s = (', '.join(row))
    if any("Open Positions, " in s): 
    # gives TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable !!!
        print(s)
```

The code prints perfectly well without the `if any("....` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! The code is:

```
import csv

key = ['Open Positions', 'Status']

with open('eggs.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',' )

for row in reader:

    # print(row)  # Check to see content of csv in list

    s=row[0:2]    # number of columns against key
    if s == key:
        print(row)
```